# Laravel Dusk sees hidden text

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, laravel-dusk

I'm trying to test quite simple stuff with Laravel Dusk (PHP).

I've got a `div` containing a product description, generated with multiple html tags inside of it, like so :

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 product_description_container">
   {!! $product->description !!}
</div>
```

My CSS is setting a max-height and is hiding whatever overflows this height :

```css
.product_description_container {
    max-height: 380px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

To test that the description is well truncated, my test sets a 20 lines description :

```php
create(Product::class, ['description' => 'line 01 <br>line 02 <br>line 03 <br>line 04 <br>line 05 <br>line 06 <br>line 07 <br>line 08 <br>line 09 <br>line 10 <br>line 11 <br>line 12 <br>line 13 <br>line 14 <br>line 15 <br>line 16 <br>line 17 <br>line 18 <br>line 19 <br>line 20 <br>']);

$this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
   $browser
      ->visit('/myproductroute')
      ->assertSee('line 01')
      ->assertSee('line 10')
      ->assertSee('line 15')
      ->assertDontSee('line 16')
});
```

When running my test, I've got this error :
`Saw unexpected text [line 16] within element [body].`

But here is the screenshot given to me by Dusk :
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyNS4.png)

It seems that `assertSee()` does not only `sees` but is also able to reach what is hidden.

How would I make this work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to solve this.

Here the description text I'm creating is only `text <br>` so there is no way for Dusk to dissociate what elements are and aren't visible. It just takes the whole `text <br> text <br> ...` as visible.

To make it work, I had to wrap my lines into `<p>` tags :

```php
create(
   Product::class, 
   ['description' => 
     '<p>line 01</p>
      <p>line 02</p>
      <p>line 03</p>
      ...'
   ]);
...
```